# Concerning the $k$-algebra $k[x,x^{-1},y]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, jacobian

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $R_{-1}:=k[x,x^{-1},y]$
be the $k$-algebra of polynomials in $x,y$ containing the inverse of $x$, denoted by $x^{-1}$.

So in $R_{-1}$ we have: $xx^{-1}=x^{-1}x=1$.

Recall that in $k[x,y]$, $p,q \in k[x,y]$ are $k$-algebraically independent if and only if $\operatorname{Jac}(p,q) \neq 0$.

> Can we characterize two $k$-algebraically independent elements $\{P,Q\}$ of $R_{-1}$ in a similar way that we characterize them in $k[x,y]$?

(Perhaps here we cannot expect an "if and only if" statement, only one direction statement).

---

**Edit:**
More generally, let $m$ be a positive integer and let 
$R_{-1/m}:=k[x^{1/m},x^{-1/m},y]$
be the $k$-algebra of polynomials in variables $x^{1/m},x^{-1/m},y$,
subject to the relation $(x^{-1/m})^m x= x (x^{-1/m})^m= 1$.

> Can we characterize two $k$-algebraically independent elements $\{P,Q\}$ of $R_{-1/m}$ in a similar way that we characterize them in $k[x,y]$?

Now we should work in the field $k(x^{1/m},x^{-1/m},y)$; is the known result mentioned in the comments also valid here?

It seems to me that the answer is positive, but I am not sure how to prove it. Perhaps one can adjust the arguments in $k[x,y]$ to arguments in $k[x^{1/m},x^{-1/m},y]$?

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, what is the point in your question of introducing (the fairly standard) notation on  $x^{-m}$ ?

Comment: ok, I will delete it. Thanks.

Comment: Actually two elements in the field $k(x,y)$ are algebraically independent iif their Jacobian does not vanish, this may answer your question.

Comment: Nice! Could you please answer my question? (or at least slightly elaborate your claim).

Comment: Yes, the answer is yes.

Comment: @InfiniteLooper, please, is the same claim valid if we replace $k(x,y)$ by $k(x^{1/m},x^{-1/m},y)$? Thanks.

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper, thanks. I think that the same claim is still true, but perhaps I am missing something? Perhaps if we have an algebraic dependence and take its $m$'th power, we obtain an algebraic dependence in $k(x,y)$, then apply your claim and finally get that the original algebraic dependence was trivial.

Comment: Don't you see an isomorphism between $k(x,y)$ and $k(x^{1/m}, y)$ ?

Comment: Oh, you are right! (my argument is wrong). Thank you very much! (you can post an answer to my question, if you want).