# An injective homomorphism from $k[x,y]$ to $k[x,x^{-1},y]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $R_{-1}:=k[x,x^{-1},y]$
be the $k$-algebra of polynomials in $x,y$ containing the inverse of $x$, denoted by $x^{-1}$.

Let $F_{-1} : k[x,y] \to R_{-1}$ be an *injective* $k$-algebra homomorphism,
and denote $A_{-1}:=F_{-1}(x)$, $B_{-1}:=F_{-1}(y)$.

$A_{-1},B_{-1}$ should be algebraically independent over $k$, by the injectivity of $F_{-1}$, if I am not wrong.

> **(1)** Is it true that the Jacobian of $A_{-1},B_{-1}$ belongs to $k^{\times}=k-\{0\}$?

For example: $A_{-1}=x, B=y+x^{-1}$ 'seems' an injective homomorphism.

> **(2)** Is there something 'interesting' that can be said about such an homomorphism? (except somethimg about the Jacobian),

An example for something 'interesting': The $(1,-1)$-degree of each of $A_{-1},B_{-1}$ must be $\geq -1$.

**Remarks:**

**(i)** More generally, we can ask the same question, replacing $R_{-1}$ by $R_{n,-n}:=k[x,x^{\frac{1}{n}},x^{-\frac{1}{n}},y]$; see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147174/concerning-the-k-algebra-kx-x-1-y) relevant question.

**(ii)** Similar questions (Jacobian replaced by the commutator) can be asked for the first Weyl algebra $A_1(k)$ instead of for $k[x,y]$, with an appropriate relation $[y,x^{\frac{1}{n}}]=\ldots$.
Notice that now injectivity is automatic, since $A_1(k)$ is simple.

Any hints and comments are welcome!